# Why show OWASP Mutillidae II php WARING in kali linux?

Tags: php, linux, owasp

When i open https://127.0.0.1/mutillidae/ then my webpage show this error
[image]

I also change the permission of **LoggerAppenderFile.php** but it still error.
The php file code is

```
<?php
/**
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 *
 * @package log4php
 * @subpackage appenders
 */

/**
 * FileAppender appends log events to a file.
 *
 * Parameters are ({@link $fileName} but option name is <b>file</b>), 
 * {@link $append}.
 *
 * @version $Revision: 806678 $
 * @package log4php
 * @subpackage appenders
 */
class LoggerAppenderFile extends LoggerAppender {

    /**
     * @var boolean if {@link $file} exists, appends events.
     */
    private $append = true;
    /**
     * @var string the file name used to append events
     */
    protected $fileName;
    /**
     * @var mixed file resource
     */
    protected $fp = false;

    public function __construct($name = '') {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->requiresLayout = true;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
       $this->close();
    }

    public function activateOptions() {
        $fileName = $this->getFile();

        if(!is_file($fileName)) {
            $dir = dirname($fileName);
            if(!is_dir($dir)) {
                mkdir($dir, 0777, true);
            }
        }

        $this->fp = fopen($fileName, ($this->getAppend()? 'a':'w'));
        if($this->fp) {
            if(flock($this->fp, LOCK_EX)) {
                if($this->getAppend()) {
                    fseek($this->fp, 0, SEEK_END);
                }
                fwrite($this->fp, $this->layout->getHeader());
                flock($this->fp, LOCK_UN);
                $this->closed = false;
            } else {
                // TODO: should we take some action in this case?
                $this->closed = true;
            }        
        } else {
            $this->closed = true;
        }
    }

    public function close() {
        if($this->closed != true) {
            if($this->fp and $this->layout !== null) {
                if(flock($this->fp, LOCK_EX)) {
                    fwrite($this->fp, $this->layout->getFooter());
                    flock($this->fp, LOCK_UN);
                }
                fclose($this->fp);
            }
            $this->closed = true;
        }
    }

    public function append(LoggerLoggingEvent $event) {
        if($this->fp and $this->layout !== null) {
            if(flock($this->fp, LOCK_EX)) {
                fwrite($this->fp, $this->layout->format($event));
                flock($this->fp, LOCK_UN);
            } else {
                $this->closed = true;
            }
        } 
    }

    /**
     * Sets and opens the file where the log output will go.
     *
     * This is an overloaded method. It can be called with:
     * - setFile(string $fileName) to set filename.
     * - setFile(string $fileName, boolean $append) to set filename and append.
     */
    public function setFile() {
        $numargs = func_num_args();
        $args    = func_get_args();

        if($numargs == 1 and is_string($args[0])) {
            $this->setFileName($args[0]);
        } else if ($numargs >=2 and is_string($args[0]) and is_bool($args[1])) {
            $this->setFile($args[0]);
            $this->setAppend($args[1]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFile() {
        return $this->getFileName();
    }

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getAppend() {
        return $this->append;
    }

    public function setAppend($flag) {
        $this->append = LoggerOptionConverter::toBoolean($flag, true);        
    }

    public function setFileName($fileName) {
        $this->fileName = $fileName;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getFileName() {
        return $this->fileName;
    }


}
```

How can i solve this problem ?
I found a solution in http://fanli7.net/a/bianchengyuyan/PHP/20130723/398120.html here but i failed. If this problem is unsolvable then it can occur a big problem for my lab testing ?

Comment: It's not the PHP file that has the wrong permissions, but a temp file it's trying to write to. Look at the second warning.

Comment: Yes,its missing a directory. But how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I find the solution. Actually you setup a old version of **mutillidae**. So it was buggy program. Then i find a new version. Here is the download link [enter link description here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mutillidae/files/mutillidae-project/LATEST-mutillidae-2.6.19.zip/download?use_mirror=heanet&r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fmutillidae%2F%3Fsource%3Dtyp_redirect&use_mirror=heanet). After you setup it,it will be awesome.